# How do you pass an array full of variables into a function in PowerShell?

Tags: arrays, powershell, switch-statement

I'm writing a script that would be made easier if I can pass an array (`$arrUserTemplates= $Mailbox1, $Mailbox2, $Mailbox3`) into a function, but I can't seem to figure it out. I'm passing the vars through using `Param($arrUserTemplates, $Mailbox1, $Mailbox2, $Mailbox3)` but the script seems to be ignoring it and not passing the variables inside the `$arrUserTemplates`.

This can reproduce the issue (the function is quite long, with a switch inside):

```
$arrUserTemplates= $Mailbox1, $Mailbox2, $Mailbox3

Function CreateMailboxes{
    Param($StorePrefix, $Store, $SharedMailboxPass, $StoreEmailOU, $EcommSharedMailboxOU, $DomainController, $arrUserTemplates, $Mailbox1, $Mailbox2, $Mailbox3)
    Foreach ($MailboxUser in $arrUserTemplates){
         Write-host "arrUserTemplates: $arrUserTeamplates"
    }
}

CreateMailboxes $StorePrefix $Store $SharedMailboxPass $StoreEmailOU $EcommSharedMailboxOU $DomainController $arrUserTemplates $Mailbox1 $Mailbox2 $Mailbox3
```

This returns simply "`arrUserTemplates:` " three times.

I'm calling it using:
`CreateMailboxes $StorePrefix $Store $MailboxPass $StoreEmailOU $EcommSharedMailboxOU $DomainController $arrUserTemplates $Mailbox1 $Mailbox2 $Mailbox3`

I need it to pass the variable through the foreach loop on the value of $arrUserTemplates because I'm then using everything it's this function builds (which also includes a switch) to run a New-ADUser:

```
  New-ADUser -Name $MailboxUser -SamAccountName $MailboxUser -UserPrincipalName $UPN `
   -DisplayName $DisplayName -Description $Desc -Enabled $True `
   -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $MailboxPass -Force) `
   -ChangePasswordAtLogon $False -PasswordNeverExpires $PasswordNeverExpires -CannotChangePassword $CannotChangePassword `
   -Path $OU -Server $DomainController
```

Comment: 'This [displays] "arrUserTemplates: " three times.' - that seems expected to me. Why would it be using something other than $arrUserTemplates in the loop?

Comment: Well, let's start with `$arrUserTeamplates` having an extra 'a' in it. Next, what I think you want there is `Write-Host "arrUserTemplates: $MailboxUser"`.

Comment: $arrUserTemplates= @($Mailbox1, $Mailbox2, $Mailbox3)

Comment: @user2864740 Mostly I did that as a test to see what would be happening. I was hoping it would... Actually, that test was invalid because of what TheMadTechnician pointed out.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician I mistyped the $arrUserTemplates in this example. I had to sanitize. It's spelled correctly in my script. I made that change in the Write-Host, and $MailboxUser is still null

Comment: @f6a4 I just made that change as well, still same thing - $MailboxUser isn't being populated with anything. The end goal is to pass the value of $MailboxUser (which will be something like "MyMailboxName" to the rest of the function.

Comment: When I change it to `Write-Host "arrUserTemplates: $MailboxUser"` and define `$Mailbox1 = 'Mailbox1'`, `$Mailbox2 = 'Mailbox2'`, and `$Mailbox3 = 'Mailbox3'` I get the expected output. Are you sure that `$Mailbox1`, `$Mailbox2`, and `$Mailbox3` are defined before `$arrUserTemplates` is defined?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician So that makes sense. However, I'm defining it after the declaration of $arrUserTemplates. Basically what I think needs to happen is that in the function, I pass $MailboxUser as an object containing the value, not the value itself. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

So the main issue here is that you are defining `$Mailbox1`, `$Mailbox2`, and `$Mailbox3` after you define `$arrUserTemplates`. If you want to be able to change the values of `$arrUserTemplates` after you make it by changing the values of the variables it *references*, then that's the key right there... the `[ref]` type. If you create your variables first, even with `$null` values, you can assign them as reference variables when you create your array, and then when you change the values of the variables later the array reflects the changes without further intervention. For example, this code:

```
$Mailbox1,$Mailbox2,$Mailbox3 = $null
$arrUserTemplates = [ref]$Mailbox1,[ref]$Mailbox2,[ref]$Mailbox3

"arrUserTemplates initial value:"
$arrUserTemplates

$Mailbox1 = 'Mailbox1'
$Mailbox2 = 'Mailbox2'
$Mailbox3 = 'Mailbox3'

"arrUserTemplates final value:"
$arrUserTemplates
```

Will create this output:

```
arrUserTemplates initial value:

Value   
-----   



arrUserTemplates final value:
Mailbox1
Mailbox2
Mailbox3
```

This shows that the values of the variables in the array were blank, and then after I change the variables the values in the array are updated to match.